# Переработка модуля Оплата наличными в точке выдачи для OpenCart

Tags: opencart, php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте, в виду отсутствия нужного мне модуля, который бы выводил только на заданные товары метод оплаты "Наличными на пункте выдачи", решил переработать уже готовый модуль добавив в него данную функцию, но столкнулся вот с такой проблемой

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/virtwww/w_elbrust-ru_dc1f47bd/http/catalog/model/payment/cash_in_a_delivery_point.php on line 25Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in/home/virtwww/w_elbrust-ru_dc1f47bd/http/catalog/model/payment/cash_in_a_delivery_point.php on line 27
```

И вот собственно код самого файла из которого выдаются ошибки:

```
<?php 
class ModelPaymentCashInADeliveryPoint extends Model {
    public function getMethod($address, $total) {
        $this->load->language('payment/cash_in_a_delivery_point');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_geo_zone_id') . "' AND country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id'] . "' AND (zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "' OR zone_id = '0')");

        if (!$this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_geo_zone_id')) {
            $status = true;
        } elseif ($query->num_rows) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }

        if ($this->cart->getSubTotal() < $this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_total')) {
            $status = false;
        }

        $method_data = array();

        if ($status) {
            $have_special = false;

            $cash_in_a_delivery_point_products = json_decode($this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_products'));
            foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $products) {
                if (array_search($products['product_id'], $cash_in_a_delivery_point_products) !== false) {
                    $have_special = true;
                }
            }

            if ($have_special) {
                $quote_data = array();

                $quote_data['cash_in_a_delivery_point'] = array(
                    'code'         => 'cash_in_a_delivery_point.cash_in_a_delivery_point',
                    'title'        => $this->language->get('text_description'),
                    'cost'         => 0.00,
                    'tax_class_id' => 0,
                    'text'         => $this->currency->format(0.00)
                );

                $method_data = array(
                    'code'       => 'cash_in_a_delivery_point',
                    'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
                    'quote'      => $quote_data,
                    'sort_order' => $this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_sort_order'),
                    'error'      => false
                );
            }
        }

        return $method_data;
    }
}
?>
```

Модуль пытался переработать взяв его за основу, и пытался выдрать функцию применимую по товарам вот из этого модуля.
В административных файлах сделал корректные изменения в админке вся работает как часы. А вот в пользовательской части выдаёт вот такую вот ошибку... В пхп я только новичок поэтому очень прошу вашей помощи в данном вопросе. 
Мною внесены изменения в следующие файлы: 
\admin\controller\payment\cash_in_a_delivery_point.php
\admin\language\russian\payment\cash_in_a_delivery_point.php
\admin\view\template\payment\cash_in_a_delivery_point.tpl
\catalog\model\payment\cash_in_a_delivery_point.php

И собственно сам модуль уже с изменениями внесенными мною: [http://filebeam.com/...4e0d4c6dceb77ab](http://filebeam.com/b6a5cf28d7ccdb9664e0d4c6dceb77ab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В json_decode нужно передавать json-строку, а у тебя в json_decode попадает массив. Вот и ошибка

Comment: А если возможно поясните, пожалуйста, как передать json-строку

Comment: @KeH192, вот здесь $this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_products') у вас должна быть json-строка. Что на самом деле там находится?

Comment: Немного не понимаю что означает json-строка? А там у меня я так понимаю написана выборка данных из массива?

Comment: @KeH192, почитай что такое json http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=1212

Comment: Из ходя из данного материала я так понимаю Данная строчка: json_decode($this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_products'));
возвращает объект JSON как объект PHP? 
Но в чём именно неверно? Почему он выдаёт ошибку?

Comment: @KeH192, ошибка в том, что в $this->config->get('cash_in_a_delivery_point_products') находится НЕ json-строка. Вот и проверяйте что у вас там лежит

Comment: Не могу разобраться в чём дело...:( Не можете ли вы доделать этот модуль? Не бесплатно естественно.